# ExceptionValidationRule doesn't react to exceptions

Tags: wpf, debugging, validation, exception

I have an `ExceptionValidationRule` on my TextBox:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="textStyleTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox"
    {Binding Path=MyProperty, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textStyleTextBox}" />
```

and `MyProperty` looks like that:

```
private int myProperty;

public int MyProperty
{
    get { return myProperty; }
    set
    {
        if(value > 10)
            throw new ArgumentException("LOL that's an error");
        myProperty = value;
    }
}
```

In `DEBUG` mode, application crashes with unhandled exception `"LOL that's an error"` (WPF Binding Engine doesn't catch this and I think it should...).

In `RELEASE` mode, everything works fine.

Can someone tell me, *why the hell* is this happening? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have an UnhandledException event attached?

Answer (score 8):

The solution is not so obvious nor well documented, but simple enough.
The reason Visual Studio breaks for exceptions when running in debug mode is because it's configured that way.

In the Debug menu, select "Exceptions...". In this dialog you control how VS handles exceptions. Simply **uncheck "User-unhandled"** for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions", press OK and run your project again.

Comment: Thank you so much..I've been breaking my head due to the same problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: So then what happens an exception is fired and WPF *doesn't* gracefully catch it.  Does the Debugger still work then?